# Get the week correspoding to a day on viewpager

Tags: android

I was trying to implement a weekview in a pager, For that I am passing a date to a function which is

```
public static String[] getpreviousweekDate(Calendar calendar, int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.e("Position index", pos+" "+calendar);


     Calendar c = calendar;
        // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, pos * 7);
        // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String[] days = new String[7];

          for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
             {
                  days[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
                   c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
             } 
     return days;
 }
```

We call the function by,

```
  indexTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        indexTime.set(year1, month1-1, day1);           
        positionIndex = -1;
        // Getting the current week details
        Weekdays = Utilities.getpreviousweekDate(indexTime,positionIndex);
```

on swipping I am calling the function

```
@Override
protected void next() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    positionIndex = positionIndex+1;
    Weekdays = Utilities.getpreviousweekDate(indexTime,positionIndex);
    Log.e("The date", Weekdays[0]);     
}
```

The problem is week is skipping in constant order.. like on first swipe I am getting the correct week, second time one week is skipping am getting third so on.. but the position index is correct.. 
please somebody help me to figure it out

Comment: when did you call next() function? Inside which method?

Comment: when swipe event detects

Comment: are you swiping a view pager? If so then get the position from  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener() method and try proceeding with that position.but  I am not sure  about whether this is requirement or  not.

Comment: positioni is correct.. I am taking that position actually

Comment: Do you mean that you are getting position from viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()  method ? If so what is the need of again adding +1?